# Xero API - Batch timeout

Tags: php, xero-api

I'm trying to batch my invoicing requests to Xero using the PHP-lib, but anything more than 10-15 requests and it times out.

An 18 invoice request of 70kb is taking 5 minutes!

This is from both my work PC and our AWS instance (both in Australia).

Can't seem to improve the performance and a batch size of 10 doesn't really do it for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible reasons you are getting poor performance:

1. Inefficient code (unlikely)
2. Networking issues (possible)
3. Underlying data / performance issues within Xero (most likely)

So my money would be on 2 or 3 :)

The best way to narrow this down would be to try running some tests against a fresh Xero organisation like the [demo company](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/development-accounts/).

If you are still seeing issues with speed then it may be networking / connectivity related.

If not, then it points to a problem with the amount of data in your Xero organisation.

Be aware that Xero is designed as small business accounting software so the general guidance on [system limits](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/xero-api-limits/#title13) may not match up to the volumes you are creating if your system has large volumes of data.

If you are still struggling, getting using the [Xero support resources](http://developer.xero.com/support/) might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks. We are looking into migrating to a different platform :)